# Información de bloc de notas a TextBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

necesito de su ayuda con lo siguiente:

Estoy buscando información dentro de un archivo de texto, este archivo tiene código de película y nombre de película, necesito que al presionar un boton llamado BUSCAR me agregue el nombre a un TextBox ya que la búsqueda se esta realizando por código.

```
 public List<string> BuscarPelicula(string cod)
    {
        List<string> Movies = new List<string>();
        string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("Peliculas.txt");

        foreach (string linea in lineas)
        {
            string[] partes = linea.Split(';');

            if (partes[0] == cod)
            {
                Movies.Add(linea);
            }
        }

        return Movies;
    }
```

[image: Formulario de búsqueda]

Answer (score 1):

En la propiedad `Text` de tu `TextBox`, coloca lo que deseas mostrar. Ejemplo:

```
TextBox1.Text = "Nombre";
```

Comment: pero no le explicas como trabajar con el valor que retorna el metodo `BuscarPelicula()` que es una lista

Comment: El `TextBox` no es un control pensado para mostrar informacion, sino para ingresarla y posteriormente procesarla, si lo que deseas es mostrar una lista de nombres (peliculas en este caso), lo mejor es un `DataGriedView` o un `ListBox` por ejemplo. Simplemente lo que guardas en tu lista, lo usas despues para llenar alguno de esos controles.

Answer (score 0):

Estas retornando una `lista de string`, por lo tanto puede haber mas de una concidencia, asignar este a un textbox simple no se puede, no al menos sino determinas de alguna forma cual sera de todos los valores posibles el que quieres visualizar

Si podrias mostrar por ejemplo el primero usando

```
List<string> result = BuscarPelicula("codigo");

if(result.Count > 0)
{
    string linea = result[0];
    string partes = linea.Split(';');

    //imagine que si la posicion 0 es el cod la 1 seria el nombre
    txtNombre.Text = partes[1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por qué retornas una lista de string, si estás buscando por código? Imagino que si buscas por codigo, el resultado es solo 1. Yo lo haría de esta forma

```
public string BuscarPelicula(string cod)
{
    var pelicula = "";
    string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("Peliculas.txt");

    foreach (string linea in lineas)
    {
        string[] partes = linea.Split(';');

        if (partes[0] == cod)
        {
            pelicula = partes[1]; //O donde sea que este el nombre
        }
    }

    return pelicula;
}
```

Y en el evento del boton pondria:

```
textBoxNombrePelicula.Text = BuscarPelicula(textBoxCodigoPelicula.Text);
```

Ahora, si el codigo de la pelicula pudiese traer mas de un nombre, como dice Orion, deberias cambiar el TextBox por un ListBox, o algun otro control compuesto y llenarlo a partir de la lista. Saludos.